# Limit of exponential functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Why

[image]

I know that for calculating this limit a Taylor series expansion around x=0 is done for the function, and after taking the limit of it's Taylor series expansion the result of the limit is obtained.

My question is why in this case a Taylor series expansion must be done before taking the limit?

Comment: It need not be done, you could differentiate $5$ times and take the limit, but that is much more unpleasant.

Comment: but your result is right

Comment: I know that it can not be done a Taylor series expansion that carelessly for taking limits of other functions, but why in this case for this specific function it works by doing a Taylor expansion? is it because of the properties of the exponential function? that it's derivative  is the same as the original function?

Comment: I tried taking the derivative 5 times and then the limit, but it was messy and the limit needed L'hopitals rule and it got even much more messy, so then I decided to expand the function and take the limit of the expansion and it worked

Comment: @copets. This is the fastest way to do, for sure (just using the series expansion of $e^{kx}$)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici so I can do any limit of any function just by first taking the Taylor series expansion of the function and then taking the limit of its Taylor expansion?

Comment: @copets. I shall confess that I felt in love with Taylor series more than 60 years ago. I work all limits using them. Just have a look at some of my answers on this site (this one is not too bad - I hope - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925916/how-can-i-find-this-limit-involving-thrice-iterated-logarithm/925936#925936)

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$ e^{x} = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n!}\tag{1} $$
it follows that:
$$ \frac{e^{bx}-e^{ax}}{x} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{b^n-a^n}{n!}x^{n-1} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} x^n \tag{2} $$
so:
$$ \left.\frac{d^5}{dx^5}\left(\frac{e^{bx}-e^{ax}}{x}\right)\right|_{x=0} = 5!\cdot [x^5]\left(\frac{e^{bx}-e^{ax}}{x}\right) = \color{red}{\frac{b^6-a^6}{6}}\tag{3}$$
as wanted.