# How can I approximate these two functions?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation, limits-without-lhopital

I have a doubt: I have to compute a limit with Taylor series. In particular, my doubt is related to this composition of functions.
$$\text{sin}(x + \text{log}(x+5))$$  [as $x\to 0$ from the right].
How can I approximate this sine, and this log?

As far as I know, I can't simply put Taylor expansions here, because: sine doesn't tend to zero, and log doesn't tend to 1. So, I can't use them here.

Is there a method I can use whenever I have
"log(number not equal to 1 + x)" to approximate this stuff?

I'm confused.

Comment: Note that a Taylor series incorporates a lot of information about limits (e.g. derivatives), so if one is trying to prove something without circular reasoning, from first principles, care is needed to unpack information taken from a Taylor series.

Comment: Nice translation of Italian "problem" to English "doubt" :)

Comment: @Salcio but that's true, it's a doubt, not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion, when composing Taylor series, starting from the inside to the outside uses to make life easier.

Using your example
$$\log(x+5)=\log (5)+\frac{x}{5}-\frac{x^2}{50}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$x+\log(x+5)=\log (5)+\frac{6 x}{5}-\frac{x^2}{50}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\sin (x+\log (x+5))=\sin (\log (5))+\frac{6}{5}  \cos (\log (5))x-\frac{36 \sin (\log(5))+\cos (\log (5))}{50} x^2 +O\left(x^3\right)$$

Trying for $x=0.1$, this would give
$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{10}+\log \left(\frac{51}{10}\right)\right)\sim \frac{4964 \sin (\log (5))+599 \cos (\log (5))}{5000}=0.987431$$ while the exact value is $0.987474$.

Comment: my calculus' professor said otherwise, "the last function I compute is the first I approximate"

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini Propose this one  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925916/how-can-i-find-this-limit-involving-thrice-iterated-logarithm/925936#925936

Answer (score 1):

$\sin{(x+\log(x+5))}=  \sin{(x)}\cos{\log{(x+5)}}+\cos{x}\sin{(\log{(x+5)})}$ by the trig identity.

It's limit as $x\to 0$ is $\sin{(\log(x+5))}$

Assuming going forward that $log$ has base $e$...

Taylors' might be applicable if you start with the reciprocal of the log's argument.

$\ln{(x+5)}=-\ln{(\frac{1}{x+5})}\approx-\ln{(1-4/5)}\approx-1\cdot(-4/5)$

since $\ln(1-x)\approx -x$

$\sin{(4/5)} \approx 4/5-\frac{(4/5)^3}{3!}$

Comment: where does "4" come from? (in this statement " (−ln(1−4/5)≈−1⋅(−4/5)) ")